# how do i fix TypeError: expected a character buffer object on line 4 in main.py in my code when i run it

Tags: python

```
decoder_exe = ""
for i in range(0,5):
  number = input("give me a number that has 5 digits")
  decoder_exe = number.index(0)
  print(decoder_exe)
```

instead of printing out the 0 index of `number`, it gives me an error
i don't know how to fix it, I searched it up but it didn't give me answers i was looking for.

Comment: Are you looking to print the index of when 0 comes in the number, Or get the 0th index of the number?

Comment: 0th index of a number

Comment: Please format your code as code, and include the full stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: @CrazyChucky There is no error message.

Comment: `number` is a string. `number.index(x)` searches the substring `x` in that string. `x` must be a string, too. You must read about how to use the method correctly.

Comment: @12944qwerty the title of the question is an error message.

Comment: Ah, oops. Missed it

Answer (score 1):

```py
number[0] # Will grab the 0th place in `number`
```

Doing `number.index(0)` will search for the instance where `0` (int) is found in the string of `number`.

Please try doing research in the future. A quick google search would be able to answer this.

**See:**

- [str.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.index)
- [Common Sequencing Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: Why does it give me this error
TypeError: 'instancemethod' does not support indexing on line 4 in main.py

Comment: Can you paste your full traceback

Comment: decoder_exe = ""
for i in range(0,5):
  number = input("give me a number that has 5 digits")
  decoder_exe = number.index[0]
  print(decoder_exe)

Comment: That's not your traceback, that's your code.

Comment: And you did `number.index[0]`.... It should be `number[0]`. `.index()` is a method, not an attribute you can index. Please look at python docs